# merging ActiveRecord objects and their children together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have to identical models called `DraftPost` and `PublishedPost`. What I try to do it to find  draft posts and published posts from a specific site and then merge them together.

```
draft_posts = DraftPost.where(:site_id => params[:site_id]).includes(:comments)
#=> 3 draft posts 

published_posts = PublishedPost.where(:site_id => params[:site_id]).includes(:comments)
#=> 2 published posts

# here I want to merge the draft_posts to the published_posts. e.g;
published_posts.merge(draft_posts)
#=> here the result should be 3 published posts (update the existing two and create one new)
```

How would you do this? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried draft_post + published_post ?

Comment: You should use STI instead of creating two tables.

Comment: @hauleth: tnx, its an already existing project and I need to continue working on this.. can't change this now.

Comment: @tokhi, I disagree. That mindset will leave you buried in technical debt before too long. This is an easy thing to change, as the interface to the AR objects would remain the same. Little to no business-logic code would need to change. This assumes that DraftPost and PublishedPost are nearly identical concepts, which it seems from your post.

Comment: the requirement is quite complex.. I just tried to simplify the question, its not something small to change and this is customer requirement.

Comment: How do you know for existing draft post which published post to update? Is there some unique identifier that appears in both the draft post and the published post record?

Comment: yeah there is a unique identified.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
published_posts << draft_posts.collect
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` to concatenate the two arrays:

```
all_posts = published_posts + draft_posts
```